# ruby-processing app.rb error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to this forum and I would like to ask a question. I have installed ruby-processing on my linux (Ubuntu distribution) machine. I would like to create art, but I get this error message when I attempt to run my code:

rp5 run sketch.rb

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/app.rb:8: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/app.rb:45: , unexpected ':' (SyntaxError)

    mouse_pressed:  :mousePressed,
                  ^
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/app.rb:8:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/runners/base.rb:8
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/runners/base.rb:6:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-processing-2.4.4/lib/ruby-processing/runners/run.rb:6
```

I have looked at the app.rb file, but I cannot seem to understand why this error is occurring. I would very much appreciate your help.

Kind Regards 
Jack

Comment: Without seeing any context it's difficult to say. It also *looks* like you're running Ruby 1.9, but if you're not actually, you cannot use the new hash syntax.

Comment: Please post the output of `ruby -v`

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. The output is posted below:

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: By context do you mean code, some of the app.rb code will be posted:

Comment: module Processing
class App < PApplet
include Math
include HelperMethods
alias_method :oval, :ellipse
alias_method :stroke_width, :stroke_weight
alias_method :rgb, :color
alias_method :gray, :color
def self.method_added(method_name) #:nodoc:
methods_to_alias = {
mouse_pressed: :mousePressed,
mouse_dragged: :mouseDragged,
mouse_clicked: :mouseClicked,
mouse_moved: :mouseMoved,
mouse_released: :mouseReleased,
key_pressed: :keyPressed,
key_released: :keyReleased,
key_typed: :keyTyped
}
if methods_to_alias.keys.include?(method_name)
alias_method methods_to_alias[method_name], method_name
end
end

Comment: rubygems.org is where i downloaded ruby-processing 2.4.4. It is a ruby  wrapper for Processing code art framework.

Comment: @user3762947 try editing the original question to include that code, rather than writing it in a comment.